# onChildAdded returns duplicated data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Issue is that when A stores a java object using the setValue function, it will be reflected in the firebase console with no duplications, but unfortunatly onChildAdded will be executed multiple times according to the number of duplications it returns.

Important note: when my application is fired and I have added no value
at this time, onChildAdded will return the exact & non-duplicated values that have been stored in the firebase console. But as mentioned above, the issue happens when I store a new data object, where it will be stored in the firebase console without duplication, but the onChildAdded will create multiple duplications for this new stored object!

The code of the Data Model class that has been stored in the Firebase's console:

```
package drawingModelData;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pen {

    private  ArrayList<Float> moveToCoordinates;
    private  ArrayList <Float> lineToCoordinates;
    private ArrayList<Float> quadToCoordinates;
    private int strokeColor;
    private int strokeWidth;

    public Pen (){
        moveToCoordinates = new ArrayList<>(2);
        lineToCoordinates = new ArrayList<>(2);
        quadToCoordinates = new ArrayList<Float>();
    }

    public void setMoveToCoordinates(float x, float y) {
        moveToCoordinates.add(0f);
        moveToCoordinates.add(0f);

        moveToCoordinates.set(0, x);
        moveToCoordinates.set(1, y);
    }


    public void setLineToCoordinates(float x, float y) {
        lineToCoordinates.add(0f);
        lineToCoordinates.add(0f);

        lineToCoordinates.set(0, x);
        lineToCoordinates.set(1, y);
    }

    public void setQuadToCoordinates(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
        quadToCoordinates.add(x1);
        quadToCoordinates.add(y1);
        quadToCoordinates.add(x2);
        quadToCoordinates.add(y2);
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(int strokeColor) {
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    }

    public int getStrokeColor() {
        return strokeColor;
    }

    public int getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getMoveToCoordinates() {
        return moveToCoordinates;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getLineToCoordinates() {
        return lineToCoordinates;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getQuadToCoordinates() {
        return quadToCoordinates;
    }
}
```

The Firebases's Codes that been used to store and return the data:

```
board0DBRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + snapshot.getKey() + ", Value " + snapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});

String boardItemForDB = board0DBRef.push().getKey();

Map<String, Object> DATA  = new HashMap<String, Object>();

DATA.put( "a", pen.getQuadToCoordinates());
DATA.put("b" ,pen.getLineToCoordinates());
DATA.put("c", pen.getMoveToCoordinates());

board0DBRef.child(boardItemForDB).setValue(DATA);
```

With:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase; 
DatabaseReference board0DBRef; 

firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
board0DBRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Board0");
```

And this is the JSON file exported from the real-time database console

```
{
  "Board0": {
    "-NBaQ1hsWEdQ8e8jfno0": {
      "a": [
        287.40234375,
        914.2578125,
        285.8282165527344,
        911.815185546875,
        284.25408935546875,
        909.37255859375,
        282.2027282714844,
        906.395263671875,
        280.1513671875,
        903.41796875,
        276.78955078125,
        898.291015625,
        273.427734375,
        893.1640625,
        263.05816650390625,
        875.205810546875,
        252.68862915039062,
        857.24755859375,
        244.23464965820312,
        836.911865234375,
        235.78067016601562,
        816.576171875,
        231.94952392578125,
        796.96484375,
        228.1183624267578,
        777.353515625,
        227.5712432861328,
        755.10546875,
        227.0241241455078,
        732.857421875,
        228.2040557861328,
        712.0361328125,
        229.3839874267578,
        691.21484375,
        232.53750610351562,
        669.8369140625,
        235.69100952148438,
        648.458984375,
        241.21624755859375,
        627.6552734375,
        246.7415008544922,
        606.8515625,
        253.85009765625,
        585.7490234375,
        260.95867919921875,
        564.646484375,
        270.43902587890625,
        545.890625,
        279.9193420410156,
        527.134765625,
        291.63824462890625,
        506.9345703125,
        303.35711669921875,
        486.734375,
        319.550537109375,
        467.6796875,
        335.74395751953125,
        448.625,
        351.7040100097656,
        431.328125,
        367.6640625,
        414.03125,
        383.87725830078125,
        400.537109375,
        400.0904235839844,
        387.04296875,
        414.1638488769531,
        376.61773681640625,
        428.2372741699219,
        366.1925048828125,
        442.07720947265625,
        358.2266845703125,
        455.91717529296875,
        350.2608642578125,
        470.58245849609375,
        344.24908447265625,
        485.24774169921875,
        338.2373046875,
        502.2078552246094,
        333.6962890625,
        519.16796875,
        329.1552734375,
        537.0115966796875,
        326.99169921875,
        554.8552856445312,
        324.828125,
        573.3057250976562,
        324.23046875,
        591.7561645507812,
        323.6328125,
        609.4300537109375,
        325.9619140625,
        627.10400390625,
        328.291015625,
        643.134521484375,
        333.2373046875,
        659.1649780273438,
        338.18359375,
        672.086669921875,
        344.4005432128906,
        685.00830078125,
        350.61749267578125,
        695.598388671875,
        357.0929260253906,
        706.1884765625,
        363.568359375,
        716.1141357421875,
        372.1502990722656,
        726.0397338867188,
        380.73223876953125,
        733.9068603515625,
        391.54205322265625,
        741.77392578125,
        402.35186767578125,
        747.01904296875,
        415.7406005859375,
        752.26416015625,
        429.12933349609375,
        754.2264404296875,
        446.02850341796875,
        756.1887817382812,
        462.92767333984375,
        754.3673095703125,
        480.7870788574219,
        752.5458984375,
        498.646484375,
        744.2771606445312,
        519.4296875,
        736.0084228515625,
        540.212890625,
        724.942138671875,
        563.345703125,
        713.8757934570312,
        586.478515625,
        700.701416015625,
        610.2060546875,
        687.5270385742188,
        633.93359375,
        673.2900390625,
        657.95703125,
        659.0531005859375,
        681.98046875,
        644.9493408203125,
        706.009765625,
        630.8455200195312,
        730.0390625,
        616.2130126953125,
        754.642578125,
        601.58056640625,
        779.24609375,
        587.6033325195312,
        803.85546875,
        573.6260986328125,
        828.46484375,
        561.6184692382812,
        853.6572265625,
        549.61083984375,
        878.849609375,
        539.8404541015625,
        901.712890625,
        530.0701293945312,
        924.576171875,
        523.724853515625,
        946.5576171875,
        517.3795776367188,
        968.5390625,
        514.0665283203125,
        988.7568359375,
        510.7535095214844,
        1008.974609375,
        510.87347412109375,
        1027.443359375,
        510.99346923828125,
        1045.912109375,
        514.531982421875,
        1063.783203125,
        518.0704345703125,
        1081.654296875,
        524.076904296875,
        1097.08642578125,
        530.0833740234375,
        1112.5184326171875,
        539.637939453125,
        1127.494140625,
        549.1925048828125,
        1142.4698486328125,
        561.935302734375,
        1155.6396484375,
        574.6781616210938,
        1168.8095703125,
        592.721923828125,
        1175.864013671875,
        610.765625,
        1182.91845703125,
        624.5576171875,
        1182.474853515625
      ],
      "b": [
        638.349609375,
        1182.03125
      ],
      "c": [
        287.40234375,
        914.2578125
      ]
    },
    "-NBaQO22Ehat0ALjMWjM": {
      "a": [
        462.744140625,
        313.0859375,
        461.35986328125,
        318.212890625,
        459.9755859375,
        323.33984375,
        459.0217590332031,
        335.429931640625,
        458.06793212890625,
        347.52001953125,
        457.765380859375,
        377.057861328125,
        457.4627990722656,
        406.595703125,
        460.219482421875,
        430.9150390625,
        462.9761657714844,
        455.234375,
        466.402587890625,
        476.919921875,
        469.8290100097656,
        498.60546875,
        473.2528076171875,
        520.578125,
        476.67657470703125,
        542.55078125,
        479.7127685546875,
        565.396484375,
        482.7489318847656,
        588.2421875,
        486.1727294921875,
        611.9638671875,
        489.59649658203125,
        635.685546875,
        493.16131591796875,
        659.7177734375,
        496.7261657714844,
        683.75,
        500.152587890625,
        705.734375,
        503.5790100097656,
        727.71875,
        505.56048583984375,
        746.48046875,
        507.5419921875,
        765.2421875,
        507.82147216796875,
        782.5390625,
        508.1009826660156,
        799.8359375,
        507.18707275390625,
        814.2700805664062,
        506.273193359375,
        828.7042236328125,
        507.20489501953125,
        840.8909301757812,
        508.1366271972656,
        853.07763671875,
        509.2940979003906,
        863.48193359375,
        510.4515686035156,
        873.88623046875,
        511.78076171875,
        882.4845581054688,
        513.1099853515625,
        891.0828857421875,
        514.0345458984375,
        897.1476440429688,
        514.9590454101562,
        903.21240234375,
        515.482421875,
        906.684326171875
      ],
      "b": [
        516.005859375,
        910.15625
      ],
      "c": [
        462.744140625,
        313.0859375
      ]
    },
    "-NBb9loplZIj60V5cN9o": {
      "a": [
        286.875,
        781.25,
        285.38031005859375,
        778.807373046875,
        283.8856201171875,
        776.36474609375,
        279.40582275390625,
        763.452880859375,
        274.9260559082031,
        750.541015625,
        268.792724609375,
        728.7763671875,
        262.65936279296875,
        707.01171875,
        260.27447509765625,
        688.853515625,
        257.8895568847656,
        670.6953125,
        258.273193359375,
        648.16015625,
        258.6568298339844,
        625.625,
        263.25,
        602.7587890625,
        267.8431701660156,
        579.892578125,
        274.291259765625,
        559.677734375,
        280.7393493652344,
        539.462890625,
        288.5150146484375,
        522.154296875,
        296.29071044921875,
        504.845703125,
        304.5374755859375,
        490.30426025390625,
        312.7842102050781,
        475.7628173828125,
        321.53802490234375,
        462.7079772949219,
        330.2918395996094,
        449.65313720703125,
        341.31427001953125,
        435.6225280761719,
        352.33673095703125,
        421.5919189453125,
        366.1409912109375,
        407.654052734375,
        379.94525146484375,
        393.7161865234375,
        396.195068359375,
        381.03851318359375,
        412.44488525390625,
        368.36083984375,
        429.073974609375,
        356.889404296875,
        445.7030334472656,
        345.41796875,
        462.96563720703125,
        336.9072265625,
        480.22821044921875,
        328.396484375,
        498.4242248535156,
        322.2353515625,
        516.6202392578125,
        316.07421875,
        534.6790771484375,
        312.833984375,
        552.7379760742188,
        309.59375,
        569.884521484375,
        309.2861328125,
        587.0311279296875,
        308.978515625,
        602.824951171875,
        311.5929870605469,
        618.6187744140625,
        314.20745849609375,
        631.9264526367188,
        319.0470886230469,
        645.234130859375,
        323.88671875,
        656.0743408203125,
        331.1795654296875,
        666.91455078125,
        338.472412109375,
        676.9518432617188,
        346.9519348144531,
        686.9891357421875,
        355.43145751953125,
        696.461181640625,
        365.9828186035156,
        705.9332275390625,
        376.5341796875,
        714.7192993164062,
        390.51422119140625,
        723.50537109375,
        404.4942626953125,
        730.869140625,
        419.087890625,
        738.2328491210938,
        433.6815185546875,
        743.1556396484375,
        449.69677734375,
        748.078369140625,
        465.7120361328125,
        750.9462890625,
        483.06402587890625,
        753.8141479492188,
        500.416015625,
        755.2696533203125,
        517.701171875,
        756.72509765625,
        534.986328125,
        755.9486083984375,
        553.431640625,
        755.1720581054688,
        571.876953125,
        752.6737670898438,
        590.9169921875,
        750.1754760742188,
        609.95703125,
        746.360107421875,
        630.4619140625,
        742.5447998046875,
        650.966796875,
        737.1474609375,
        672.0517578125,
        731.7501220703125,
        693.13671875,
        725.16357421875,
        715.40234375,
        718.5770263671875,
        737.66796875,
        710.6748046875,
        761.1025390625,
        702.7725830078125,
        784.537109375,
        694.2032470703125,
        808.5546875,
        685.6339111328125,
        832.572265625,
        676.80224609375,
        856.595703125,
        667.9705200195312,
        880.619140625,
        659.66357421875,
        905.22265625,
        651.3565673828125,
        929.826171875,
        642.7832641601562,
        955.0185546875,
        634.2099609375,
        980.2109375,
        626.5582275390625,
        1005.412109375,
        618.9064331054688,
        1030.61328125,
        613.62109375,
        1055.8056640625,
        608.3358154296875,
        1080.998046875,
        603.7189331054688,
        1104.4443359375,
        599.10205078125,
        1127.890625,
        598.0302124023438,
        1149.5849609375,
        596.9583740234375,
        1171.279296875,
        597.8680419921875,
        1190.9169921875,
        598.7777099609375,
        1210.5546875,
        602.5545654296875,
        1226.28271484375,
        606.3314208984375,
        1242.0106201171875,
        613.6282348632812,
        1255.324951171875,
        620.925048828125,
        1268.639404296875,
        630.5732421875,
        1279.55419921875,
        640.221435546875,
        1290.468994140625,
        652.9228515625,
        1299.1455078125,
        665.6243286132812,
        1307.8218994140625,
        682.8577270507812,
        1313.30517578125,
        700.0911254882812,
        1318.7884521484375,
        718.96337890625,
        1320.426513671875,
        737.8356323242188,
        1322.064453125,
        756.2913818359375,
        1320.0341796875,
        774.7470703125,
        1318.00390625,
        794.647705078125,
        1310.416015625,
        814.54833984375,
        1302.828125,
        833.2782592773438,
        1290.248046875,
        852.0081787109375,
        1277.66796875,
        868.888427734375,
        1261.2763671875,
        885.7687377929688,
        1244.884765625,
        899.1092529296875,
        1228.7744140625,
        912.44970703125,
        1212.6640625,
        920.2583618164062,
        1196.55078125,
        928.0670166015625,
        1180.4375,
        931.6397705078125,
        1164.6142578125,
        935.2125244140625,
        1148.791015625,
        933.9205322265625,
        1133.263671875,
        932.6285400390625,
        1117.736328125,
        928.1593017578125,
        1101.6259765625,
        923.6900634765625,
        1085.515625,
        916.7364501953125,
        1070.322021484375,
        909.7827758789062,
        1055.1285400390625,
        901.1302490234375,
        1040.73046875,
        892.4777221679688,
        1026.332275390625,
        880.4939575195312,
        1014.0601196289062,
        868.5101928710938,
        1001.7879638671875,
        854.4459228515625,
        991.6820068359375,
        840.3817138671875,
        981.5760498046875,
        821.6927490234375,
        973.5603637695312,
        803.0037841796875,
        965.544677734375,
        782.0819091796875,
        960.7225341796875,
        761.1600341796875,
        955.900390625,
        738.4935302734375,
        953.2548828125,
        715.8269653320312,
        950.609375,
        693.4188232421875,
        949.138671875,
        671.0106201171875,
        947.66796875,
        648.3309326171875,
        947.0791015625,
        625.6511840820312,
        946.490234375,
        605.07421875,
        945.6142578125,
        584.4972534179688,
        944.73828125,
        567.0791015625,
        942.11328125,
        549.6609497070312,
        939.48828125,
        535.9382934570312,
        935.7993774414062,
        522.2156372070312,
        932.1104736328125,
        511.81805419921875,
        926.3345336914062,
        501.4204406738281,
        920.55859375,
        493.36309814453125,
        912.709228515625,
        485.3057861328125,
        904.85986328125,
        480.9227600097656,
        895.1206665039062,
        476.53973388671875,
        885.3814697265625,
        477.9674072265625,
        868.1383666992188,
        479.39508056640625,
        850.895263671875,
        486.45751953125,
        830.8206787109375,
        493.5199279785156,
        810.74609375,
        502.87103271484375,
        790.82421875,
        512.22216796875,
        770.90234375,
        522.894287109375,
        750.1015625
      ],
      "b": [
        533.56640625,
        729.30078125
      ],
      "c": [
        286.875,
        781.25
      ]
    },
    "-NBbWVa2cPI6Di4pTGgd": {
      "a": [
        228.8671875,
        1125.78125,
        226.8626251220703,
        1122.459716796875,
        224.85806274414062,
        1119.13818359375,
        224.1599884033203,
        1116.453857421875,
        223.4619140625,
        1113.76953125,
        228.27293395996094,
        1102.779541015625,
        233.08395385742188,
        1091.78955078125,
        271.62847900390625,
        1045.445556640625,
        310.17303466796875,
        999.1015625,
        367.5770263671875,
        946.6748046875,
        424.9810485839844,
        894.248046875,
        473.43603515625,
        856.091796875,
        521.8909912109375,
        817.935546875,
        553.8743896484375,
        795.2919921875,
        585.8577880859375,
        772.6484375,
        600.555908203125,
        764.0286865234375,
        615.2540893554688,
        755.408935546875,
        618.8121337890625,
        755.47998046875,
        622.3702392578125,
        755.5510864257812,
        621.8701171875,
        764.5994873046875,
        621.3700561523438,
        773.6478881835938,
        609.2318115234375,
        803.08251953125,
        597.093505859375,
        832.5172119140625,
        579.4390258789062,
        867.6394653320312,
        561.7845458984375,
        902.76171875,
        548.6998291015625,
        933.8515625,
        535.6151123046875,
        964.94140625,
        535.14404296875,
        981.8939819335938,
        534.6729736328125,
        998.8465576171875,
        542.7091674804688,
        1004.682373046875,
        550.745361328125,
        1010.5181884765625,
        567.2940673828125,
        1005.7432861328125,
        583.8427124023438,
        1000.9683837890625,
        608.8720703125,
        985.8201293945312,
        633.9014892578125,
        970.671875,
        656.3201904296875,
        953.685546875,
        678.7388916015625,
        936.69921875,
        697.34619140625,
        920.5712890625,
        715.9534912109375,
        904.443359375,
        728.1439208984375,
        897.5314331054688,
        740.3344116210938,
        890.6195068359375,
        745.447265625,
        889.2550659179688,
        750.56005859375,
        887.890625,
        753.517333984375,
        888.916015625,
        756.474609375,
        889.94140625,
        761.6083984375,
        893.1914672851562,
        766.7421875,
        896.4415283203125,
        784.9820556640625,
        897.8349609375,
        803.2219848632812,
        899.2283935546875,
        844.113037109375,
        892.4257202148438,
        885.0040893554688,
        885.623046875,
        928.599609375,
        878.01171875
      ],
      "b": [
        972.1951293945312,
        870.400390625
      ],
      "c": [
        228.8671875,
        1125.78125
      ]
    },
    "-NBbWVhTA8prRxo6Ncal": {
      "a": [
        275.009765625,
        1599.21875,
        275.20355224609375,
        1594.62646484375,
        275.3973693847656,
        1590.0341796875,
        281.7419738769531,
        1575.442138671875,
        288.0865783691406,
        1560.85009765625,
        313.8519287109375,
        1526.257080078125,
        339.6172790527344,
        1491.6640625,
        373.3277282714844,
        1474.900390625,
        407.0381774902344,
        1458.13671875,
        437.6478271484375,
        1456.8798828125,
        468.25750732421875,
        1455.623046875,
        482.6756591796875,
        1468.997314453125,
        497.09381103515625,
        1482.3714599609375,
        506.9387512207031,
        1498.676025390625,
        516.78369140625,
        1514.980712890625,
        524.2693481445312,
        1532.1124267578125,
        531.7550048828125,
        1549.244140625,
        538.1934204101562,
        1562.647216796875,
        544.6318359375,
        1576.0501708984375,
        551.3106689453125,
        1581.963623046875,
        557.9894409179688,
        1587.876953125,
        568.3466796875,
        1586.3785400390625,
        578.7039794921875,
        1584.880126953125,
        594.7960815429688,
        1573.2850341796875,
        610.88818359375,
        1561.68994140625,
        628.3709716796875,
        1551.53125,
        645.8536987304688,
        1541.37255859375,
        663.8954467773438,
        1544.482177734375,
        681.9371948242188,
        1547.591796875,
        698.556396484375,
        1560.4384765625,
        715.1756591796875,
        1573.28515625,
        730.3394775390625,
        1585.9033203125,
        745.5032348632812,
        1598.521484375,
        763.94580078125,
        1604.421875,
        782.3883056640625,
        1610.322265625,
        791.9754028320312,
        1609.1650390625
      ],
      "b": [
        801.5625,
        1608.0078125
      ],
      "c": [
        275.009765625,
        1599.21875
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The issue is the data returned by the onChildAdded getting duplicated(When I open the logs, I show that this function is executed multiple times with duplicated data, but in the console no duplicated data is found, so the data in the console is fine, but I don't want the onCHild added to executed multiple times duo to duplication of data )

Comment: How is `board0DBRef` defined? Pease also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Dear Alex, I have added the JSON file in the issue description, thank you for your comment.

Comment: And how is `board0DBRef` defined?

Comment: I have just created an object of the firebase DB, and made a child called "Board 0", this will be held at the reference board0DBRef

Comment: FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference board0DBRef;
   firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
board0DBRef =  firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Board0");

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you show the output from `println` that highlights the duplicate calls?